# How can we add logo of a item in describe step in DSpace Jspui

Tags: dspace

Available input types are :-

input-type (Required): Defines the kind of interactive widget to put in the form to collect the Dublin Core value. Content must be one of the following keywords:
**onebox** 
**twobox** 
**textarea**
**name** 
**date** 
**series** 
**dropdown** 
**qualdrop_value** 
**list**

I just want to add a file upload control in my describe step so which input type i can use?? and how??

Answer (score 0):

The brief answer is, you can't do that. You would have to customise the describe step's code to add the file upload functionality. Perhaps you could expand on your question a little bit more so that we can understand what you're trying to do. Why isn't the normal file upload step good enough?

Comment: i just want to add logo / thumbnail of my item at describe step and then select the item,  finally the complete step . So is there is any way to add a file upload at describe step ?  how can i do it ? can a input type doesn't have a type file upload ?

Comment: As I wrote in my response, you can't do that.